# new to TOR and looking for help to setup

Tags: configuration, anonymity

am not a PC or IT genius - so pardon the ignorance (and hope I am coming to the right place to help).
seeing as I live in a "free" country (Australia) and am now constantly having my privacy invaded am looking at using TOR for browsing/downloading but don't really know how to set it up properly so I am protected/secure.  Have read as much as I can at the webpage but to be honest it is a little confusing for someone like me (sorry for that but am trying to learn!!!!). 
What  would like to know what/how to do is:
1) to not be identified when visiting any site I usually go to
2) to not be identified when downloading from any site I usually go to

am a big fan of what happens here - as I think it is great that people are fighting the good fight against big-brother!!!
any help or assistance that someone can give me would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I can help you to build a home router or mobile one: it can distribute wifi and secure all devices attached. Need help?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to use Tor is to use the Tor Browser Bundle, which is a modified version of Firefox that comes with (obviously) Tor, and has a lot of cool tweaks that help protect your privacy. It is already pre-configured to use Tor!

To download the Tor Browser Bundle go to the official website of the Tor Project (don't go anywhere else!) : https://www.torproject.org/download/download-easy.html.en

By using the Tor Browser Bundle, only the TBB's traffic is routed through Tor, it does not route all of your traffic through Tor. Be sure to read the warnings here about potential errors some users may do: https://www.torproject.org/download/download-easy.html.en#warning